# PHP 5.3 Windows APC config crashes all php files

Tags: php, apc

I have installed apc on windows using php 5.3

It works fine without using any config settings.  As soon as i put any apc settigns in the config file all php files stop working.

For example apc.shm etc etc

There are no entires in the apache logs

EDIT:

I am running a 64 bit, windows 7 box.

PHP extensions:

```
;extension=php_bz2.dll
extension=php_curl.dll
;extension=php_fileinfo.dll
extension=php_gd2.dll
;extension=php_gettext.dll
;extension=php_gmp.dll
;extension=php_intl.dll
;extension=php_imap.dll
;extension=php_interbase.dll
;extension=php_ldap.dll
extension=php_mbstring.dll
;extension=php_exif.dll      
extension=php_mysql.dll
extension=php_mysqli.dll
;extension=php_oci8.dll     
;extension=php_oci8_11g.dll  
;extension=php_openssl.dll
;extension=php_pdo_firebird.dll
extension=php_pdo_mssql.dll
extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
;extension=php_pdo_oci.dll
;extension=php_pdo_odbc.dll
;extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll
;extension=php_pdo_sqlite.dll
extension=php_pgsql.dll
;extension=php_phar.dll
;extension=php_pspell.dll
;extension=php_shmop.dll
;extension=php_snmp.dll
;extension=php_soap.dll
;extension=php_sockets.dll
;extension=php_sqlite.dll
;extension=php_sqlite3.dll
;extension=php_sybase_ct.dll
;extension=php_tidy.dll
extension=php_xmlrpc.dll
;extension=php_xsl.dll
;extension=php_zip.dll
extension=php_apc.dll
```

Answer (score 0):

It would help by providing a little more system configuration details such as 32/64 bit and if PHP is running as fast-cgi or not.

Edit: Sorry I totally missed Windows in the topic title. Still stands a little more information would help finding the cause.

PS: Are you loading more extensions which can conflict?

--

You might consider checking the PHP.ini as it looks most like the cause of your problems, see:

http://www.devcomments.com/q425690/Installing-PHP-APC-on-Windows-Apache

http://www.rawseo.com/news/2009/06/09/how-to-install-alternative-php-cache/